# integral $\int \frac{1}{(1-x^2)^{\frac{1}{3}}} \, dx$

Tags: calculus

$$\int \frac{1}{(1-x^2)^{\frac{1}{3}}}\,dx$$

$\underline{\bf{\text{My Try}}}$ Let $(1-x^2) = t^3$. then $-2x\,dx = 3t^2\,dt$ or $\displaystyle dx = -\frac{3t^2}{-2x}\,dt = \frac{3t^2}{-2\cdot \sqrt{1-t^3}}\,dt$

So $\displaystyle  = -\frac{3}{2}\int t^1\cdot (1-t^3)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\,dt$

Now our integral is converted into in this form $\int x^m\cdot(a+bx^n)^p \, dx$

So $m=1$ and $n=3$ and $\displaystyle p=-\frac{1}{2}$

Now How can I solve it

Help Required

Thanks

Comment: Wolfram suggests that the answer is [not too nice](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+%281-x%5E2%29%5E%28-1%2F3%29).

Answer (score 2):

It is easy to check that your integral equals to $F^2_1(\frac13, \frac12; \frac32; x^2) + c$, where $F^2_1$ is hypergeometric function that can not be expressed using elementary functions.